# Vim в VS Code или Vim

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

Недавно начал изучать Vim. Очень понравилась его возможность всё делать клавиатурой. Но вот, что то больно мне не нравится интерфейс, да и не получается, что то у меня поставить плагины на него. Но недавно я увидел, что этот же самый Vim можно реализовать в VS Code. Там интерфейс поприятней + уже есть подсветка всего что мне нужно. Но есть пара вопросов.

1. Все ли возможности Vim реализованы в VS Code? Например я знаю, что для vim есть в виде плагина есть очень мощный поиск файлов в VS Code такое есть?
2. Работает ли автодополнение слов в режиме вставки? Например,если я пишу phpin... то оно высвечивает вариант с phpinfo().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем вам VSCode если вы хотите работать с Vim? Vim очень мощное средство, которое не требует дополнительной оболочки. Ну или вы делаете что-то неправильное.

Во-первых, подсветка. Вы написали, что в VSCode уже есть подсветка всего что нужно, но Vim тоже может подсвечивать синтаксис. Нужно в `.vimrc` только включить строку `syntax on`. И настраивать подсветку можно так, как вам только заблагорассудится (для этого нужно редактировать соответствующие файлы, но это более продвинутый уровень).

Во-вторых, интерфейс. Если вас это заботит, то не стоит тогда пользоваться Vim, так как здесь все делается через клавиатуру. Полумеры это не для этого редактора. Ну или пользуйтесь `gvim`.

В-третьих, установка плагинов предельно просто, если у вас есть плагин для их установки. Я пользуюсь `vundle`. Скачиваете его с гитхаба, устанавливаете в соответствии с инструкцией, и заносите нужные строки в `.vimrc`. И все. Дальше если вам нужно установить плагин, просто ищете его на гитхабе, и вносите в `.vimrc` такую строку

```
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim' // строка в кавычках соответствует репозиторию
```

В-четвертых, автодополнение. Вообще в Vim есть совой `autocomlete` (кажется), но я не советую его использовать. Сам я пользуюсь `clang-complete`, который помимо автодополнения предоставляет ещё и проверку синтаксиса — очень удобная вещь.

Подытожу: если вы хотите пользоваться Vim вместе с какой-то IDE - это плохая идея. Vim очень гибкий и расширяемый инструмент, который сам может быть почти IDE. Тут либо вы переходите на Vim, либо вы делаете что-то совсем не то.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ. Насчёт плагинов. Я пытался устанавливать vundle по инструкции, но в ответ на PluginInstall получаю что такой командные нету. Ответа на эту проблему ч не нашел( точней нашел ответы, но они не работают в моем случае).

Comment: @ДимаСурок скорее всего вы неверно установили `vundle` или не включили нужные строки в ваш `.vimrc`

Comment: @ДимаСурок вы точно редактировали ваш `.vimrc` в соответствии с указаниями в `readme`?

Comment: Да, .vimrc менял, а vundle установил через команду git в инструкции.

Comment: @ДимаСурок а у вас файлы `vim`a находятся в нужной директории? Тобишь вы точно установили куда нужно?

Comment: Vim установил через команду sudo apt-get install vim. Установило оно в $HOME/.vim

Comment: Вы были правы, походу не в той папке стоял vim. Если бы я запускал просто командой `vim`, то надо сохранять в $HOME/.vim. Если через `sudo vim`, то в папку /root/.vim, и .vimrc в  /root/.vimrc.